# How to display different pages with angular view and routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two html files, and i need to make them display with angular.

This is my js:

```
  var app = angular.module('test', ['ui.bootstrap','ngRoute']);

app.controller('submitController', ['$scope','$http','$timeout',function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

  $http.get('podaci.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.data = data;

  $scope.counter = $scope.data.vreme;

  });

   $scope.countdown = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        if( $scope.counter > 0 ){
          $scope.counter--;
        }
         /*  else 
        go to the other page */
       $scope.countdown();
      }, 1000);
    };


  $scope.answers = [];
  $scope.text = '';
  $scope.submit = function() {
    if ($scope.text) {
      $scope.answers.push(this.text);
      $scope.text = '';
    }

  };
  $scope.remove = function($index) { 
    $scope.answers.splice($index, 1);     
  }

}]);

  app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/quiz.html',
    controller: 'SubmitController'
   }).
     when('/result', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/result.html',
    controller: 'ResultController'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
  }]);
```

and this is quiz.html, the second html is empty:

http://pastebin.com/AQEngDpP

There is a timer on the page, and when the time is up it should go to the other page. or when you click the button that i still haven't made. But i can't get that second page show up.

Comment: Where is the ResultController defined?

Comment: looks like you have added content in `ng-view` which is gonna replace by $routeProvider, also you missed to added angular-route.js

Comment: yup, thats it, thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-route:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Example can be seen here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07